# How to use strtok to get tokens within tokens?

Tags: c, string, file, strtok

I am trying to separate tokens from each line of a file and print them. The delim I am using is ",". However, the last string for some line have tokens with "," within the string. How do I get the entire string with the "," inside?

```
char *buff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
char *tmp;

while (fgets(buff, 256, FILENAME) != NULL) {
    tmp = strtok(buff, ",");
    printf("%s\n",tmp);

    tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf("%s\n",tmp);

    tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf("%s\n",tmp);
    
}
```

The lines from the input file looks like this:

```
This,is,a
Code,in,"c,language"
rat, mouse, "rat, mouse"
```

I am trying to have an output like this:

```
This
is
a
Code
in
c, language
rat
mouse
rat, mouse
```

Comment: Are double quotes required for the string to be tokenized? This can help to find a solution.

Comment: No, just have to get rid of the double quotes which might be there in the last token of each line

Comment: Walk the string char by char... when you find a comma what's before the comma is a token; when you find a quote start sub-search inside quote until you find the matching quote.

Comment: @ReajuddinRabbi Write a proper parser that properly parses `"`, `strtok` is the wrong way here.

Comment: `Code,in,"c,language"` results in `c, language`? Where does the comma between `c` and `language` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a free sunday is a great time for little simple coding, here's a parser that I wrote in short time. It doesn't parse escape sequences and has little error handling, but could help you get started.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void parse(FILE *file) {
    int c;
    // keep track if we are in quotes or not
    bool inquote = false;
    // keep track if the field started or not
    bool infield = false;
    
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {

        if (!infield) {
            // ignore leading spaces before fields
            if (c == ' ') continue;
            infield = true;
        }

        switch(c) {
        case '"':
            inquote = !inquote;
            continue;
        case ',':
            // if comma is in quotes, just print it
            if (inquote) break;
            // fallthrough
        case '\n':
            // comma or newline are field separators
            printf("\n");
            infield = false;
            continue;
        }
        // output the character
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}

int main() {
    parse(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

[it outputs on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4G7GWe):

```
This
is
a
Code
in
c,language
rat
mouse
rat, mouse
```